# SQL views with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, view

I have a SQL view to integrate with my application. I have been using Entity Framework till now. But the problem is that when I add a view to Entity Framework it starts treating my view as a table.

What I really want to know is, am I missing on something? Also if I use Nhibernate will this problem be resolved? Will it treat the view as a view only?

This view is a very complex query which has multiple joins and aggregation. That is why I am using a view.

Comment: And what's wrong with that kind of 'like a table' treatment?

Comment: Better you post the code to help us to help you

Comment: See: [Entity Framework: Creating a model using views instead of tables](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/entity-framework-creating-a-model-using-views-instead-of-tables/) or [How to Use SQL Server Views with the Entity Framework](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1990/how-to-use-sql-server-views-with-the-entity-framework/) - using view with EF shouldn't be a real problem at all...

Comment: Entity framework provides a gateway of sorts for running queries & hydrating the results.  This should happen when you query a table & when you query a view.  So, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: There is a Visual Studio extension for it, check out this post: [Frustrated by lack of support for SQL-Views in ADO.NET Entity-Framework Designer?](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/09/03/frustrated-by-lack-of-support-for-sql-views-in-ado-net-entity-framework-designer.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem is that when I add a view to Entity Framework it
>   starts treating my view as a table.

No it doesn't. If you add view to your model through wizard (EDMX designer) it will internally handle the view as a defining query which makes readonly entity. At entity level (the conceptual model) you don't see a difference because it is just another entity / class but if you try to make changes to instance of that class and save them you will get an exception (unless you map stored procedures or custom SQL commands to insert, update and delete operations for that entity).

Edit:

Database views as well as other database specific features like stored procedures or SQL functions are only for database first scenario (when you are using *Update model from database* in the designer).

Using *Generate database from model* is for Model first scenario where you tell VS: "Here is my model and I want some database to store it." First of all only information from conceptual model is used (original mapping and database description is replaced with a new one every time you run this command so even mapping to original database can be broken). It cannot create database specific features for you because it doesn't know that class should be mapped to view and moreover it doesn't know how should the view be created (the query from original view is unknown).

You can force VS to create the view for you but it is a lot of work in T4 templates where you will have to somehow provide SQL creation script for the view.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. But when I select "Generate database from model" it creates a table instead of views. Is there any other way to create the database?

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, this was really helpful. What I am thinking of doing is, combine entity framework and some db migration tool like fluent migration. So that I can manage sql views and other db specific items and still have the benefits of entity framework which would be creating entities from database.

Comment: Fluent migrations currently don't support mapping created through designer - you must use code mapping to use migrations.