# Entity Framework View Number of Reads

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a fairly complex view for searching people.  There are several linked tables like address, phone, email, memberships and so on.  The view is named vSeachMember and so is the entity.

If I run a query in SQL Mgmt Studio like this:

```
Select * FROM vSearchMember WHERE FirstName like '%kelly%'
```

It runs in about 2 seconds and has about 160,000 reads (found using sql profiler)

If I run this code in my MVC app using EF (_db is the context):

```
var p = _db.vSearchMembers.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains("kelly") ).ToList();
```

It takes about 25 seconds and there are 12,000,000 reads.

I have tried to pre-generate my views which didn't help.  I have also tried turning lazyload off.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Code generated by EF:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
...
FROM (SELECT  
[vSearchMember].[Id] AS [Id],
...     
FROM [dbo].[vSearchMember] AS [vSearchMember]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE ( CAST(CHARINDEX(LTRIM(RTRIM(@p__linq__0)), [Extent1].[FirstName]) AS int)) =
1',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'kelly'
```

The "..." above are left out for brevity, it just has the same syntax for each field (29 of them).

Comment: What is vSearchMembers? Is that your context?  A List of members?

Comment: It's the name of the view.  I'll update the question to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that this is the SQL that was generated. I'd expect not a `=` comparison but a `>=`. A `=` would mean "starts with".

Comment: Good eye, yes that code generated is for a starts with. Changing it to a contains doesn't have much effect and actually makes it a little slower.  So the problem remains!

Answer (score 1):

Check the SQL that EF is generating. Separate the query from the extraction in your code like so and breakpoint on the second line

```
var query = vSearchMembers.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains("kelly") )
var p = query.ToList();
```

You can get the SQL by inspecting query.

I don't know why, but willing to bet it's quite different to your hand-coded SQL query.

Interested to see vSearchMembers DDL.

FURTHER EDIT:

Just to make the code in the comment a bit more readable, can you try something like this:

```
var members = db.Members.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains("kelly");
var query = from m in members
            from s in vSearchMembers.Where(s => s.MemberId == m.MemberId)
            select s;
var p = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question with the code that EF generates.  It is quite different.  Any idea how to make it less terrible?

Comment: That's a nasty expression. I ran a .Conatins() query against a table and it can up with the the WHERE .. LIKE .. expression, so it has to be something to do with the view.

Comment: I've not used views with EF - how did you create it? Is it an MVC construct? Ref this answer, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768908/sql-views-with-entity-framework) - indicates that the view may be treated as a defining query (an expression tree) not as a table. This isn't a fix but may explain the rummy code.

Comment: You may want to try a small fiddle like this (assuming Members is a table containing the FirstName):  var members = db.Members.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains("kelly");
 var query = from m in members
             from s in vSearchMembers.Where(s => s.MemberId == m.MemberId)
             select s;
 var p = query.ToList();

Comment: The view was added to EF using the "Update Model From Database" wizard in the edmx.  You just select the view and it adds it to your model as an entity.  In frustration yesterday I ended up writing a stored procedure and running that using EF.  It is very fast, as fast as running the query in sql studio.  I might end up going this route for heavy searches.  I'll try out you code suggestion though and let you know what happens.

Comment: Cool, I was thinking about a stored proc also (but have kind become a linq bigot these days). I'll try out some views in my app and if anything useful comes up will post it here.